How to control our emotion and compulsion and through which mantra or stotra can it be done?
What are some of the mantras and stotras which can make our minds more concentrated and tranquil?
Suppose a person becomes sad, happy or compulsive in any instance of time according to the surrounding which mantra can help them to keep an even balance of mind. Not too excited not too dull.

You are asking this which lord krishna said in bhagavat Gita ——>O best among men [Arjuna], the person who is not disturbed by happiness and distress and is steady in both is certainly eligible for liberation. For this the more naam jap you do more you will be able to tolerate both happiness and distress

Phala struti Ma Durga 32 names says. It will make the aspirant fearless.
